# Snowpack & Peerjs: Uncaught ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable parcelRequire

Tags: javascript, parceljs, referenceerror, peerjs, snowpack

I tried to make a small app using peerjs but when I tried to `import Peer from "peerjs"`, my code crash with:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable parcelRequire`

At `http://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/peerjs.js:20`

I didn't find anything on internet. And I don't why snowpack is using parcel because I didn't install any plugin
I tried to import Peerjs with Skypack but it's same.
On the other hand, when I test to import another library, here I tested with canvas-confetti, it work. So I don't know why Snowpack doesn't like Peerjs

Comment: I find that's because PeerJS is using Parcel to bundle. The problem is that Parcel doesn't produce strict code but a module is always strict... so it can't be imported. But I don't know how to fix that without modify the peerjs file

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by adding `esModuleInterop: true` and `allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true`  to tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the peerJs library.

You can see the line of code that is causing this issue [here](https://github.com/peers/peerjs/blob/master/dist/peerjs.js#L8)
You could perhaps mitigate it by setting window.parcelRequire before importing the peerJs library. Consider filing an issue to peerJs's github.

Comment: The link is dead. It's a good idea to link to a specific commit to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar error in parcel-bundler https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1401 used by the status-widget developed by Atlassian https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/statuspage-status-widget/issues/3/uncaught-referenceerror-parcelrequire-is

Answer (score 0):

For Instance Fix

Add variable in
node_modules/
peerjs/dist/peerjs.js

```
var parcelRequire
```

instead of

```
parcelRequire
```